# Is sunsetted a valid word?

Tags: grammar

As the title says is "sunsetted" a valid word?

In my office, I heard one of the guy saying that this application is sunsetted. Is that valid?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does "sunset" mean in this text?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/13968/what-does-sunset-mean-in-this-text)

Comment: It depends on what *you* think makes a usage of a word valid.

Comment: It is jargon in a particular field, usually referring to a planned phasing out or obsolescence of a product..the end of its "day" being almost over.  So it is a valid word, but not necessarily a universally applicable usage.

Comment: It is also common for sunrise/sunset provisions in contractual agreements. Not surprising the "what does sunset" question is specifically referencing a piece of legislation.

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "valid".  I definitely hear (ostensibly) literate people say ".. has been sunsetted" when speaking of a law or a version of some computer program or some such.

Comment: Personally I'd prefer to say "That application has been sunset", on the grounds that it sounds better, and that "sunsetting" is not really an active thing that an object does, it's a passive condition imposed by others.  Verbing "sunset" in this way is not very common in the wider English speaking American culture, in my experience.

Comment: To quote a famous juggler; "the verbification of a noun is also the nounification of a verb". Oh, the horror.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Initially I though "no way!" but according to Wiktionary it is commonly used as a verb in business to refer to the retiring of a product (why one wouldn't say 'retiring' or 'phase out' is beyond me).

**sunset** (third-person singular simple present sunsets, present participle **sunsetting**, simple past and past participle **sunsetted**)

(business, politics, transitive) To phase out.
We'll be sunsetting version 1.9 of the software shortly after releasing version 2.0 next          quarter.

http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sunset#Verb

Comment: I can confirm that sunsetting is used in commercial software circles (for shame!). A sunset period is often one where limited (but often reluctant) support is given to software. You might call it software in its twilight years. For example: http://community.versionone.com/Developers/Developer-Library/Documentation/App_Catalog/Sunset_Policy_for_Integrations http://srthelpdesk.helpserve.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/423

Comment: +1 for commentary! :-)  I'm sure there is a reason somewhere but I thought the same thing - why a completely different word for something that is already described by "phased out" or "retired".  I'm thinking it's industry jargon but I'd still love to know the backstory!

Comment: **obsolete** and **retired** have a more pejorative implication than **sunsetted** does.

Comment: Also, sunsetted implies that the timeline of the project's demise has already been worked out; whereas "being retired" or "being phased out" implies there's no timeline.

Comment: Maybe it completes the idea of the "dawn of a new era".

Comment: It is in somewhat common use in S/W circles, but as a BE speaker it sounds wrong to my ears. I would have thought that sunset could already be past tense, e.g. "the product was sunset last month"

Answer (score 4):

This meaning of *sunset* is in the OED:

> to subject to, or terminate by means of, sunset legislation,

meaning that a law which is *"sunsetted"* is only valid for a certain period of time unless it is explicitly renewed. If this is the definition that was meant, to say that an application *"is sunsetted"* means that it has an expiration date, after which it no longer works, or is not supported, or is not guaranteed to work.

I believe the past tense used for this meaning is generally *"sunsetted"* and not *"sunset"*, but I wouldn't be surprised at either one.

Comment: hmmm.  Seems to me that "subsetted" would describe a portion of something.

Comment: @KristinaLopez That looks like just a typo to me.

Comment: @Chris: It was indeed a typo caused by my spelling incorrector. I've fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

The discussion on this is fascinating. Some bemoan "sunsetted" as jargon. I find it refreshing that legal types and computer programmers would use such a delightfully metaphorical term rather than something much duller, e.g. phased out or retired. I also agree with the argument above that "sunsetting" generally caries the meaning of the end being preplanned. Even from this practical vantage point, the allusion to the setting sun seems apropos to me.

Comment: No, I can't agree with you, Billy Williams, because, like most irregular verbs, <em>set / set / has set</em> is a verb in continuous use from Old English <em>settan</em> (and is in fact a deverbal verb, a causative form of the verb <em>sit / sat / has sat</em>, OE <em>sittan</em>). However, <em>sunset / sunsetted / has sunsetted</em> is a <b>denominal</b> verb derived from the noun <em>sunset</em>. Denominal verbs are more-or-less exclusively regular verbs. And <em>to sunset</em> should therefore be in line rather with the regular denominal verb <em>set / setted / has setted</em>, 'to group pu

Answer (score 0):

I have no argument about the fact that the term exists. However, sunsetted is awful. In the past tense I would use sunset, as an irregular verb, as past participle. Better yet, is to you phase out, which can be conjugated nicely as phased out.

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage. A good answer will include citations reflecting the research involved in framing the answer. An answer may be quite correct, but requires validation to be accepted. It would be good for you to edit this answer by including citations. Thanks.